# What's the difference between Design pattern, Architectural pattern, Architectural style, and Architecture?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, architectural-patterns

Can anyone please describe the differences between Design pattern, Architectural pattern, Architectural style, and Architecture? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Design Pattern generally refers to design pattern of a particular bit of code (a few objects or functions) such as Factory Pattern, or Visitor

An architectural pattern refers to the pattern design for a solution, such as Event-Driven, MVC, 3-Tier, etc.  It is usually concrete, and can be plugged into a problem with a fairly known set of parameters.

Architectural Style is more abstract, and refers to things like Separation of Layers, SOA, etc.  It is not a "solution" to a problem, but is a description of a design.

Architecture is the actual design and implementation of a given solution.  It is concrete and specific to a specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

Design pattern deals with implementaion of a common solution for ceratin problems that can happen while designing a large software application. The examples of problems which i meant here are - code duplication, maintainibility of code for future enhancement etc

Eg: Factory pattern, Dependency Injection pattern

Architectural patterns mainly deals with entire architecute of a software application. They are very re usable and generic and can be adopted based on the requirements.

Eg: MVC, REST, 3 Tier

Answer (score 1):

- An **Architectural Style** is the application design at the highest level of abstraction
- An **Architectural Pattern** is a way to implement an Architectural Style
- A **Design Pattern** is a way to solve a localized problem

For example:

- What you want to implement in your project or requirement like REST or CRUD operation with high level of abstraction is Architecture style
- How are you going to implement it is Architecture pattern
- The problems you will encounter and are going to solve is Design pattern